# How do you save dates from Ember to a Rails backend?

Tags: datetime, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

My model seems to be showing the right information for a date (which it's calling a Moment), but when I try to save data to my rails backend, "null" is sent across the wire.  I'm using the ActiveModelAdapter, is there anything else I need to do to read/write dates?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? The best practice for formatting your dates with Moment is by registering a helper - [see the guide here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/displaying_formatted_dates_with_moment_js/). An addon, e.g. [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment), can make this easier.

Your model itself shouldn't know about Moment - the date attached to your model should just be a Date object. If you've declared `dateAttribute: DS.attr("date")` in your model, it should be serialized and transmitted appropriately by Ember Data.

Comment: Ah, I'm using [a datepicker](https://github.com/soulim/ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker) to set those dates, so that must be it.  Thanks!